# How can I customize Retrofit allow to pass null as a value for path parameters?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Read this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-path-parameters

See:

```
Don’t Pass Null as Parameter Value
Retrofit doesn’t allow you to pass null as a value for path parameters and if you do, it throws an IllegalArgumentException. That means, your app will crash at runtime! Be aware of this behavior with requests that involve a path parameter. Ensure stability by verifying that the path parameter values are always not null.
```

What are the workaround for this?

There is no need to put lots of code here because Retrofit itself is saying that it is not possible.

Note: Do not tell me to change this for server-side, it's simply not possible. I know I can use JSONObject with the async task to get the data, but I want to do with Retrofit.

Comment: Maybe you can initialize as null on your retrofit Service: `param: String? = null`

Comment: use annotation @Nullable before potentially null parameter

Comment: @Aspicas what does it mean?

Comment: On your retrofit APIService, you can set the @query as null default value. For example, `@Query("myParam") param: String = null (Kotlin)`

Answer (score 1):

try to pass the empty string if its not working than pass the hashmap data and add a check validation just add those parameter that you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing an empty String `""` instead of `null` when path value is null (a simple if statement would suffice right).

Its working when I tried. I think that's the simplest workaround I can think of provided you don't need your url to remove the additional `/` from the url.

If you want the url to change too, then the workaround I can currently think of is to create another interface with the simple url (no path) and when making the API call decide which interface to call base on path's value.

Comment: it's not working, I tried passing for Integer 0 and for String ""

Comment: I tried on retrofit:2.6.0 not sure if its related to version but passing "" for String does  call the API( result will depend on the url it forms), for both GET and POST. Also I don't suppose passing 0 for int is violating any rule.  If this doesn't work I guess you'll have to do it in the other way using separate interfaces

Comment: it depends on server, they want us to pass "" or null

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but it would help others who see this.
Just simply wrap it in another class which overrides toString() and and returns Objects.toString()(which will return "null" in case of null value).

```
public class RetrofitNullableParam<T> {

    @Nullable
    private final T param;

    public RetrofitNullableParam(T param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return Objects.toString(param);
   }
}
```